# How to setup ace for multiple languages in a separate div?

Tags: ace-editor

I want to add a div-container with the ace-code editor.

For that I've create this

```
<div id="editor" class="codeeditor">
      <div id="editor-nav" class="codeeditor-nav">HTML | Javascript | CSS | PHP </div>
      <div id="editor-code" class="codeeditor-codearea"></div>
</div>
```

I want to use the sourcecode of another div for the ace-editor

```
<div id="mycontent">That the code i want to edit</div>
```

I setup the ace with this

```
var editor = ace.edit("codeeditor-codearea");
editor.session.setMode("src-min-noconflict/mode/javascript';?>");
```

How I must setup the ace that

- Does it take the content from the "mycontent"?
- and show the ace-editor in "editor-code"?

Also, I have the problem, that my content will look unpretty after adding by the editor - is there a way to prevent that?

Comment: what do you mean by unpretty?

Answer (score 0):

you can setup the editor like this

```
var editor = ace.edit("codeeditor-codearea", {
    mode: "ace/mode/javascript",
    value: document.getElementById("mycontent").textContent
});
?>");
```

or if you are using an older version of ace

```
editor.session.setValue(document.getElementById("mycontent").textContent)
```